# ¿Una clase al implementar una interfáz se convierne en una interfaz?

Tags: java, interface

```
public class Robot {

private Ibrazo brazo;
private Icabeza cabeza;

public Robot(Ibrazo brazo, Icabeza cabeza)
{
this.brazo=brazo;
this.cabeza=cabeza;
}

public void disparar()
{
    this.brazo.disparar();
}
```

}

//OTRAS CLASES E INTERFACES:

//interfaces:

```
public interface Ibrazo {
void disparar();
```

}

```
public interface Icabeza {
void cabeza();
```

}

//Clases que implementan esas interfaces:

```
public class BrazoX implements Ibrazo{
@Override
public void disparar() {
    System.out.println("Disparando con el brazo X");
}
```

}

```
public class Cabezax implements Icabeza{
@Override
public void cabeza() {
    System.out.println("Cabeza X");
}
```

}

//PARTE DONDE TENGO DUDAS:
POR QUÉ AL MOMENTO DE PASAR POR PARAMETROS "by" y "cx" NO ME SALTA ERROR SI SUPUESTAMENTE EN MI CLASE MAIN AL MOMENTO DE CREAR MI OBJETO ROBOT DEFINÍ QUE SE PASARIAN POR PARAMETROS INTERFACES Y NO OBJETOS DE TIPO BRAZO Y CABEZA YA QUE AQUÍ CREO LOS OBJETOS DE TIPO BRAZOY Y CABEZAX

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
// write your code here

   BrazoX bx=new BrazoX();
   BrazoY by=new BrazoY();
   BrazoZ bz=new BrazoZ();
   Cabezax cx=new Cabezax();


   Robot r1=new Robot(by,cx);
    r1.disparar();



}
```

}

Comment: No, no se convierte en una Interfaz, porque es una Clase, y aunque implemente una Interfaz, seguirá siendo una Clase.

Comment: Bienvenido! Te recomiendo leer [ask] y completar el [tour]. Por favor, evita las imágenes para mostrar código, es preferible que pegues texto. También estaría bien que añadieras el código faltante que completa tu pregunta: el de las interfaces

Comment: Por favor quite la imagen y añada esa imagen en texto para poder copiar y pegar directamente para nuestra prueba y además que no pierda calidad

Answer (score 1):

No, no se convierte en una Interfaz.
La función de la interfaz es que puedas implementar varios tipos de brazos: BrazoX, BrazoY, BrazoZ, etc.
Al pasarle una clase de estas el Robot no sabrá cual es la original pero al hacer brazo.dispara() ejecutara el método del tipo de brazo que le hayas pasado.

Comment: Si eso es obvio , a lo que me refiero es que al momento de crear el objeto Robot tengo que pasarle por constructor 2 interfaces cierto?, entonces yo creo los objetos brazo y cabeza que son de tipo brazo y cabeza no tipo interfaz, lo que quiero saber es porque me acepta pasarle esos objetos de tipo brazo y cabeza si no son interfaces

Comment: La cuestión es que la interfaz es un envoltorio y si la quieres utilizar vas a tener que pasarle siempre una clase que la implemente (No se le puede pasar una interfaz ya que te va a pedir que la implementes). Podrías poner la clase que le vas a pasar  al robot directamente pero lo que consigues con las Interfaces es desacoplar, de forma que sea fácil sustituir el funcionamineto de las partes de tu programa.

Answer (score 0):

Las interfaces son contratos....

Una interfaz, define como debe ser la clase.. Especifica que cosas (metodos) tiene que tener. Dependiendo el lenguaje hasta puede definir que variables puede contener.

Sin embargo, vos no pasas interfaces. Pasas clases concretas, que implementan dicha interfaz. Al definir que algo recibe una interfaz, estas diciendo que vas a recibir un objeto que al menos implementa dicha interfaz.

Ojo, por que un objeto, puede implementar mas de una interfaz. Pero al recibir algo particular de esa interfaz, solo vas a poder acceder a los metodos de dicha interfaz.

El programa maneja objetos concretos. Las interfaces, son para decirle al compilador como es un objeto, y que cosas tiene que tener si o si. Al ser un contrato, tenes que respetarlo.

Comment: Podrias produndizarme mas sobre lo que dijiste partes arriba, que al definir que algo reciba una interfaz estas diciendo que vas a recibir un objeto que al menos implemente dicha interfaz.
O podrías brindarme una pagina donde puedo leer ese detalle

Comment: Pero lo que me estas pidiendo que te explique es lo que pusiste vos como ejemplo... al pasarle new Cabezax, estas pasando un objeto que implementa la interfaz... capaz yo no estoy entendiendo donde te trabaste.... Y esto, esta explciado por todos lados en internet....

Comment: Yp no digo que este mal mi ejemplo, esta bien lo que no comprendo es que los parametros son objetos no interfaces , porque me acepta los objetos y no me sale error si en los parametros tienen que recibir interfaces

Comment: a ver.. voy a volver a tratar de explicartelo, pero crei que habia quedado claro.. Una interfaz es una promesa de como va a ser el objeto que vas a pasar.. y el objeto que pasas, tiene que implementar dicha interfaz para que lo puedas pasar. Cuando vos decis que recibis interfaces, en realidad lo que estas diciendo es que vas a recibir objetos que implementen dicha interfaz. @GeanPaulArámbuloAquijes . decime si ahi te queda mas claro...